# Flow of alternating current in an ac circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

I know that it the frequency of an alternating current is 50Hz.It changes its polarity 50 times. So in a circuit does the polarity gets changed these many times.
It seems that it is well applicable in an ac circuit. But think of the voltage we get from the transmission lines, if we connect an iron-box to a three pin plug, does the plugs except the ground changes its polarity that many times according to the frequency.

Comment: Uh, yes? What troubles you about that?

Comment: if it were so. Thinking in the view of electrons the electrons doesn't move anywhere they move forward and backward within the same place.so in a power generator does it only need some electrons to initiate a current and that's enough uh..I can't see this is as a valid point

Comment: Yes, the electrons move to and fro at a frequency of 50Hz. In an AC circuit there is no net movement of the electrons.